# Sequel auto_validation not checking strings maxlength

Tags: ruby, validation, sequel

I want to use auto_validations for my sequel models.
Documentation says:

> The auto_validations plugin automatically sets up the following types
>   of validations for your model columns:
>
> 1. type validations for all columns
> 2. not_null validations on NOT NULL columns (optionally, presence validations)
> 3. unique validations on columns or sets of columns with unique indexes
> 4. **max length validations on string columns**

Using this code (mysql2 adapter):

```
class Sequel::Model
    plugin :schema
    plugin :validation_helpers
    plugin :auto_validations, :not_null=>:presence
end

unless DB.table_exists? (:unit_types)
    DB.create_table :unit_types do
        primary_key :id
        String      :name, :null => false
    end
end

class UnitType < Sequel::Model(:unit_types)
end
```

Created table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `unit_types` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Testing it in irb:

```
irb(main):009:0> UnitType.create()
Sequel::ValidationFailed: name is not present 

irb(main):010:0> UnitType.create(name: '')
Sequel::ValidationFailed: name is not present
```

That's good, but max length validation is not working:

```
irb(main):016:0* UnitType.create(name: "abc"*1000)
Sequel::DatabaseError: Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'name' at row 1
```

What to do?

Comment: Which version of sequel are you using ? this max length validation feature seems to be added in sequel ver 4.12.0. In my laptop which uses 4.16.0, your code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ymonad is absolutly right: problem was caused by slightly outdated Sequel version!